# WP7 and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, tdd

is there any unit test framework for WP7?

I have tried both MBUnit and Visual Studio UnitTestFramework, but they can't work. I cannot reference a wp7 project since it has a different version of system.dll

Stefano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's the [WP7 version of the Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/), written by Jeff Wilcox.

Comment: NUnit looks more promising! The wilcox stuff was a chase down a neverending rabbit hole with no clear instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Check also: [NUnit Windows Phone 7](http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/)